# stackrel, vertical alignment and math operators

Tags: vertical-alignment, math-operators

In the following MnWE, the macro `\lhypbad` produces a good vertical alignment but doesn't respect the space around the math operator `<`. See the picture below. What is the best way to fix that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\leqhyp{%
    \stackrel{\text{hyp}}{\leq}%
}

\newcommand\lhyp{%
    \stackrel{\text{hyp}}{<}%
}

\newcommand\lhypbad{%
    \stackrel{\text{hyp}}{<\vphantom{\leq}}%
}

\begin{document}


$x \leqhyp 1 \lhyp y$

$x \leqhyp 1 \lhypbad y$

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Unrelated, `\text ` is the wrong macro to use here. Consider `\mathrm`. Why see what happens if you add `\itshape` to the start of your mwe.

Comment: You could use `mathtools` and its `\mathclap`  I'd also use `\scriptscriptstyle` to make is smaller. Additionally, I'd probably not even write stuff above the equal sign as it is generally bad typesetting style.

Comment: The purpose of this command is purely pedagogical : this will be used in lessons stressing the different semantic uses of symbols like `=` , `\leq` ... and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbols for `\leq` and `<` have different height. You can force the latter to be the same height as the former by using `\vphantom`, but `\mathrel` has to surround the construction. Also `{<}\vphantom{\leq}` should be used in order to avoid spurious spacing.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\leqhyp{%
  \overset{\mathrm{hyp}}{\leq}%
}

\newcommand\lhyp{%
  \mathrel{\overset{\mathrm{hyp}}{{<}\vphantom{\leq}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$x \leqhyp 1 \lhyp y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Generally speaking, `\overset` is better than `\mathrel`. In this particular case, however, `\stackrel{\mathrm{hyp}}{{<}\vphantom{\leq}}` could do, because `\stackrel` always makes a relation symbol.

Also `\mathrm` should be preferred to `\text` here, or the word “hyp” could be in italics in theorems.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and clear answer ! Good point for the theorems...